# Workbook is read only try again

Tags: excel, vba, readonly

I have this code that checks to make sure the workbook is not open/in use.
How would I modify it to try again in 5 seconds and after 3 tries then send the MsgBox?

```
 If wBook.ReadOnly = True Then
        MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try after sometimes.", vbookonly + vbCritical, "error"
        
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: `loop` and `application.wait`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
For i = 1 To 3

    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
        Application.Wait Second(Now()) + 5
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Activate
        MsgBox "write"
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next
    
If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
    MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try after sometimes.", vbookonly + vbCritical, "error"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an auxiliary method that gives you some flexibility in how much to wait depending on the arguments you pass:

```
Public Sub TryWriteMode(ByVal book As Workbook _
                      , ByVal numberOfTries As Long _
                      , ByVal secondsWaitAfterFailedTry As Long)
    Const maxSecondsWait As Long = 60
    If book Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise 91, "TryWriteMode", "Book not set"
    End If
    If numberOfTries < 1 Then Exit Sub
    '
    'Cap seconds
    If secondsWaitAfterFailedTry < 0 Then
        secondsWaitAfterFailedTry = 0
    ElseIf secondsWaitAfterFailedTry > maxSecondsWait Then
        secondsWaitAfterFailedTry = maxSecondsWait
    End If
    '
    Dim i As Long
    Const secondsPerDay As Long = 24& * 60& * 60&
    '
    For i = 1 To numberOfTries
        On Error Resume Next
        book.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not book.ReadOnly Then Exit Sub
        Application.Wait Now() + secondsWaitAfterFailedTry / secondsPerDay
    Next i
End Sub
```

In your example you could call like this:

```
If wBook.ReadOnly = True Then
    TryWriteMode book:=wBook _
               , numberOfTries:=3 _
               , secondsWaitAfterFailedTry:=5
End If
If wBook.ReadOnly Then
    MsgBox "Database is in use. Please try again later.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Read-only book"
    Exit Sub
End If
```